# How to store entries from fields to a text file?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to store the text entries from fields into a text file.
Register and login with fields, not inputs.

```
fields = "First Name", "Last Name", "Email Address", "Username", 
    "Password"


    def fetch(entries):
       for entry in entries:
          field = entry[0]
          text  = entry[1].get()
          print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) #i do not need this
          fwu = open('UserData.txt','w')     
          fwu.write(('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))) #here is the 
                                                  #problem    
          fwu.close()
```

The print is doing the right thing:

```
First Name: "1"
Last Name: "2"
Email Address: "3"
Username: "x"
Password: "y"
```

But in the text file is saved only the last field("y")

I need to create a exam program for hire tools, with register, login, account... I have other problems but I will deal with those, I hope to.

Comment: Opening a file in `w` mode overwrites the entire file. You should not open the file in the loop, instead open in before starting the loop, and close it when the loop ends.

Comment: Or you could append to the file instead of writing

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is because you do not provide a new line at the end of your string and probably related to how you open and write over your text file for every entry.

Instead you should open the file one time and then write everything with a new line at the end of each string.

I prefer to use `with open` instead of `open` and `close` as the `with open` statement will automatically close once everything has completed below it.

Try this instead:

```
fields = "First Name", "Last Name", "Email Address", "Username", "Password"

    def fetch(entries):
        with open('UserData.txt', 'w') as fwu:
            for entry in entries:
                field = entry[0]
                text  = entry[1].get()
                print('{}: "{}"\n'.format(field, text))
                fwu.write('{}: "{}"\n'.format(field, text))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's insert only the last one because it `overwrites` it in the file you need to use `newline` to get all the content in the entries to be inserted in the `text file`

```
def fetch(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))  # i do not need this
        fwu = open('UserData.txt', 'a')

        fwu.write(field+"\n"+text)  # 

        fwu.close()
```

Comment: For your case, you should open the file in `append` mode, otherwise you will get the same error as OP.  Or you should open the file outside the for loop.

Comment: I've changed that part in the code, is a good ideea but i still need to ad/remove something. I have this result in the saved file:                                               
First Name
aLast Name
bEmail Address
cUsername
1Password
2

Comment: fwu.write(field+":" + text + "\n")  this is solving the problem:                          
First Name:a
Last Name:b
Email Address:c
Username:1
Password:2